# Windows 8.1 Pro x64 Guest VM not taken all the memory configured

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I have below host machine:

- Windows 10 Home x64
- 12GB RAM

I have installed Virtualbox version 6.1.16 r140961 (Qt5.6.2) and configured a VM Guest as below:

- Windows 8.1 Pro x64
- 6144MB RAM

My problem is that VM Guest is taken only 3GB, not the 5GB configured. Why?

**VM Guest screenshots**:

[image]
[image]

**Host screenshots**:

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you see is how Virtual Machines work. You have allotted 5 GB of memory but it is only needing 3 GB for the operations it is doing.

So it just uses the memory needed and in this case 3 GB.

I have seen this for a long time with VMware Workstation and many kinds of machines. I have not needed to assign 5 GB ever. 4 GB has always sufficed and often I only see 3 GB in use. The latter depends on what the machine is doing at an instant in time.

Some physical machines may use memory for Video, but a virtual machine uses the Host Video and so does not need much Video memory. That may be true for other drivers that the Host supplies. Video is the most obvious on my own machines.

Also multiple machines (I have 3 running) may allocate memory among the machines.

Note: On another machine here with Hyper-V, not all the memory is in use, but Hyper Manager has some dynamic memory management. Each Virtualizer is going to be a bit different in this regard.

I never see more in total than the total I have allocated to all machines.

So this is a normal situation.

Comment: I'm a vivid VirtualBox user, but VirtualBox does give the full assigned memory to the guest always, unlike other VM solutions. You cannot hand out more memory than your system has to multiple vm's and depending on the need, have it being allocated more or fewer.

Comment: @LPChip I agree. A VirtualBox VM should see the allocated amount of RAM. The VM may actually use less real RAM in the host if not all memory is actually used, but the guest OS will think the available RAM is there. In this case the VM seems to think there is only 3 GB allocated to the VM, which is really strange. I've never seen that happen.

Comment: However I have Windows 7 pro x64 Guest VM with 6144MB allocated and in this case VM is taken all the 6144MB assigned. I do not understand why Win 8.1 Pro x64 Guest VM is not taken all the RAM allocated......

Comment: @Ralph Is the VM using Bios or EFI ? is PAE enabled or not ? Windows versions above 7 really like PAE, but Virtualbox doesn't enable it by default if you use the wizard and select Windows 8.1 x64 as guest type.

Comment: Is the virtualizing App bumping against the total allocated limit?

Comment: @Tonny EFI is not enabled in VM configuration. PAE is enabled.

Comment: @Ralph In that case try it with PAE off. It may make a difference in the way the virtual hardware presents itself to the guest OS. By the way: I can't reproduce the issue (I happened to have a WIn8.1 x64 image VM available, so I tried), but my host-system is a Mac so it is not entirely comparable. I can do some further experimenting with a Windows 10 host tomorrow. I'm of to bed now. Its past midnight here and I have to be up early.

Comment: @John But 3gb for a Win 8.1 Pro is not enough, then it runs so slow, programs delay so much at startup, etc. etc. For me it is not normal. Also the same machine running on a Linux host runs faster, and even a VMware VM Win 8.1 Pro in Windows host and running in VMWare is faster.

Comment: I will keep looking around for reasons.  Thanks for the update.

Comment: @John Finally I have solved. The problem was the max memory box setting checked under msconfig boot advanced options. It was set to 3072MB.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have solved it.
The problem was the max memory box setting checked under msconfig boot advanced options.
The max memory was set to 3072MB so I unchecked it, restarted vm and voila! System now recognizes all the allocated RAM, in my case, 6GB ;)

[image]