# VirtualBox Windows 10 VM only using half of memory allocated to it

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, memory, virtual-machine

I´m using a Windows 10 VirtualBox VM and it doesn´t seem to be using all of the allocated ram memory. Specs:

- Windows 10 64bit Enterprise 20H2
- Host Processor i7-6700k
- 8 cores on host / 4 cores allocated to vm
- 32GB of RAM on host machine / 16GB of RAM allocated to vm.

I´m using memory intense applications and as soon as the 8GBs are reached the VM gets sluggy. Am I missing out on something?

[image]

Comment: Open (run) MSCONFIG.EXE  .   In the Boot tab, click on Advanced Options and make sure the Maximum Memory setting is unchecked.   See:  https://superuser.com/questions/1624783/windows-8-1-pro-x64-guest-vm-not-taken-all-the-memory-configured/1624785#1624785

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering. For some reason I cannot recall, the vm is now using all the allocated ram. I tried a lot and had also tried the solution you mentioned and nothing worked. Seems to be working now - don´t ask me why :-)